# I have a 1955 Chevy pickup with after market wiring harness & floor mounted dimmer switch.

Tags: diodes

The hi beam indicator is on with Hi & lo beams. There is a low voltage on one side of the dimmer switch when pushed it is low on the other side. So the switch is working but getting bleed across. Checked the wiring and it is correct. Am I wrong in thinking that I may have to add a diode to the one side. If so what size diode and do I put it in the indicator wire? I did add LED headlights this winter but it did this before, I do not have any relays wired in the system. Driving me batty trying to get the simple indicator to work properly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate on the [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: You could at least have posted a picture of the truck :(

Comment: Didn't know how to add pic.

Answer (score 1):

A diode is not what you need.

If you take a look at this [typical 1955-era GM wiring diagram](http://www.trifive.com/garage/55%20Chevy%20Assembly%20Manual/12-27.gif) you can see the dimmer switch routes the current from the headlight switch to the desired filaments. The AWG18 light green wire is supposed to be the high beam and the beam indicator lamp.

The beam indicator lamp is effectively in parallel with the high beam filaments with the other side grounded. 
[image]

I suspect you have the **H and L connections to the dimmer switch swapped.** And maybe a corresponding swap at the headlights, or maybe the high beams are coming on without the low beams being on.

Comment: mine matches the wiring diagram, that is why I am having trouble figuring out why it still has low voltage to the low beams when Hi beams are on.